# как в Gnuplot вывести данные из цикла for в title

Tags: gnuplot

Хочу вывести данные числа 'n' из цикла for [n=2:3] в title, чтобы было
Аккумулятор 1
Аккумулятор 2
и так далее.

```
plot for [n=2:3] "ESR4.txt" using 1:n with lines smooth bezier title 'Аккумулятор' (n-1) ???
```

Как можно сделать ?